# Very strange behaviour from cake php after logging out

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications

Ok this is the scenario:

- Admin logs in
- Admin logs out
- Normal user logs in
- Redirected to admin page!

If I delete cookies stored however before logging in as a normal user, login works as expected. Another strange thing I have noticed is that the admin redirect in my login function is not actually ran when the normal user logs so they are being redirected elsewhere.

Here is some code:

Users Controller:

```
<?php
    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                //if login successful update logged in User as login does not use recursive find
                $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $this->User->read();
                $this->Auth->login($this->User->data);
                if($this->Login->isRole($this->Auth->user(), 'Admin')) {
                    //redirect admins to admin page, not ran when error occurs!!
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));  
                } else {
                    //isAuthorised in AppController takes care of redirect to registration page if required
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
                }
            } else {
                //if login unsuccessful
                $this->Session->setFlash(
                    __('Invalid username or password, please try again.'), 
                    'alert',
                    array(
                        'plugin' => 'TwitterBootstrap',
                        'class' => 'alert-error'
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        //set layout
        $this->layout = 'not_logged_in';
        //set title
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Login');
    }

    public function logout() {
        //logout
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if(parent::isAuthorized($user)) {
        //call parent method for redirect and admin permission
        return true;
    }
    switch ($this->action) {
        case 'add':
        case 'resetPassword':
        case 'login':
            //logged in users cannot access registration, login or password reset pages
            return false;
            break;
        case 'add_role':
            //check user is finshing registration or has a role request accepted
            return (!$this->Login->isRegistrationComplete($user) || $this->Login->isRoleRequestAccepted($user));
            break;
        default:
            //all loogged in users can access the rest of User controller
            return true;
            break;
    }
}
php?>
```

App Controller:

```
<?php
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'className' => 'UserAuth',
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array('Blowfish'),
        'authError' => 'Please login.',
        'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.',
    ),
    'Login'
);
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        //set values needed for all logged in pages
        $this->set('loggedIn', $user);
        $this->set('role', $user['User']['role']);  
        if($this->Login->isAccessing($this, 'users', 'logout')) {
            //never prevent user from logging out
            return true;
        }
        if($this->Login->isRole($user, 'Admin')) {
            //admin can access every action
            return true;
        } elseif ($this->request->prefix === 'admin') {
            //only admins allowed on admin pages
            throw new Exception('You do not have permission to access this page.', 1);
        }
        //get user role and requested role
        $roles = $this->Login->getRolesCurrentAndNew($user);
        if($this->Login->isRoleRequestAccepted($user)) {
            //user has an accepted role request
            $controller = 'users';
            $action = 'add_role';
            if($this->Login->isRedirectRequired($this, $controller, $action)) {
                //if user is already accessing registration this check prevents redirect loops
                if ($this->Login->isRegistrationComplete($user)) {
                    //display flash based on registration status
                    $this->Session->setFlash(
                        __('Your request for the role of '. strtolower($roles['new']) . ' has been accepted, please enter additional details.'), 
                        'alert',
                        array(
                            'plugin' => 'TwitterBootstrap',
                            'class' => 'alert-success'
                        )
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(
                        __('Please complete your registration.'), 
                        'alert',
                        array(
                            'plugin' => 'TwitterBootstrap',
                            'class' => 'alert-success'
                        )
                    );
                }
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action));
            }
        } elseif (!$this->Login->isRegistrationComplete($user)) {
            //user has not registered yet and role request is not accepted
            if(!$this->Login->isRegistrationComplete($user)) {
                //user has not completed registration yet, awaiting approval
                throw new Exception('Your registration request is awaiting approval from a member of the admin team.', 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Routes config:

```
    Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
    Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
    Router::connect('/register/role', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add_role'));
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
    Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
    Router::connect('/users/manageRoleRequest', array('controller' => 'roleRequests', 'action' => 'add'));
```

Comment: what is that `$this->Auth->login($this->User->data);` stuff? Why are you overwriting the session data after the login (which already does that)? Doesnt make sense to me. Note that you can use `contain` to contain more data (which in the end is the same than using recursive). Also note that your statement is incorrect, since you need a flat User array to pass into (see the docs!).

Comment: Because $this->Auth->login() doesn't respect my User model's recursive attribute. It says in the comment just above it.

Comment: With your code you still only result in Auth.User.User.id etc which doesnt make it any better. You should also always include the current cakephp version you are using - since this is vital for a correct answer.

Comment: I want to store the User object and its objects in the session. I have to set recursive to 2 to do that. Auth->login() just stores the User which I do not want.

Comment: Did you read the part about "contain"? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers - And if you really still want to manually log people in, you need to use it correctly: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in (note the flat 1-dim array without the User key)

Comment: I have a recursive attribute in my User model that makes any find use a recursive value of 2. I'm still quite new to CakePHP thanks for the hint will look up contains now. Although none of this actually affects the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realised that CakePHP automatically takes you to the last page you were viewing when you log out and in on the same machine, regardless of whether or not you're logging in as a different user or not.

Comment: Hi, could you marked an accepted answer? Or do you need a solution to avoid this "automagic"?

Comment: I would like a solution, but if this behavior is the norm and not something I have done then I am willing to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> property AuthComponent::$logoutRedirect
>   The default action to
>   redirect to after the user is logged out.  While AuthComponent does
>   not handle post-logout redirection, a redirect URL  will be returned
>   from AuthComponent::logout(). 
>   Defaults to AuthComponent::$loginAction.

Meaning:

```
$this->Auth->logout()
```

will return a string url. Nothing more.
You wrap it with a redirect to redirect to this url:

```
public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

So, no, Cake will only redirect you to the specific action you specified via "loginRedirect" setting.
In your case your login view.

Comment: "and if successful redirect the user to either the last page they were visiting, or AuthComponent::$loginRedirect" taken from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it seemed to work for me

```
    public function logout() {
        $logout_redirect = $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->Auth->redirectUrl($this->Auth->redirect());
        return $this->redirect($logout_redirect);
    }
```